# Memory leak with setInterval running in a Node.js Process

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I'm having an issue with `setInterval()` causing a memory leak in my Node.js application. The app is simple: it wakes up every half hour, looks in a MongoDB table to see if there's any work to do (most times it does not), and then sends an email to the records found that meet the criterion. Over time (a few days), the memory goes from 100MB to over 1GB.

I tried moving the variables outside of the setInteveral to get GC'd but no luck. Am I missing something?

I'm using New Relic to monitor the transaction, but this issue persisted prior to me adding this instrumentation.

```
const transactionName = 'email-scheduler';
let invokeTransaction = newrelic.createBackgroundTransaction(transactionName,
    function () {
      sendEmail(function (error) {
        log.info("Job completed; ending transaction.");
        newrelic.endTransaction();
      });
    }); //must be outside of setInterval to be GC'd
if (RUN_SCHEDULER) {
  setInterval(invokeTransaction, JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES * 1000 * 60);
}

function sendEmail(callback) {
  log.info('Scheduler woke up to send emails (set to send every ' + JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES + ' minutes)');
  mongo.findUsersSince(180, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      log.error("Welcome emails could not be sent: " + err);
      callback(err);
    }
    else if (result && result instanceof Array) {
      api.sendEmail(resutlt);
    } else {
      callback(null);
    }
  });
}
```

Here's the alternative version when I'm using a package like Cron instead of setInterval().  Suffers from the same issue:

```
function sendEmail(callback) {
  log.info('Scheduler woke up to send emails (set to send every ' + JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES + ' minutes)');

  try {
    new CronJob('0 */' + JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES + ' * * * *', function () {
      log.info('Scheduler woke up to send emails (set to send every ' + JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES + ' minutes)');
      mongo.findUsersSince(OKTA_WAIT_MINUTES, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          log.error("Welcome emails could not be sent: " + err);
          callback(err);
        }
        else if (result && result instanceof Array) {
          api.sendEmail(resutlt);
        } else {
          callback(null);
        }
      });
    }, function () {
      log.info('Scheduler completed job.');
    }, RUN_SCHEDULER, "America/Los_Angeles");
  } catch (ex) {
    log.error("cron job pattern not valid");
  }
}
```

Comment: curious why you are doing this: `let invokeTransaction = invokeTransaction = ...` That doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: Typo...corrected.

Comment: Why would `invokeTransaction` ever get GC'd? It's in global space, never overwritten... I would assume it would be better to put the whole logic inside a container function, using only local variables - that would make it more likely that the GC will clear them out (assuming no long-life variable is holding on to the binding scope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a XY problem. I would say that using a `setInterval` to create a scheduler in node is not really a good idea in the first place.

Rather I would use a cronjob, which sounds a lot more appropriate.

Something like [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) for example would look like this

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule')

schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', function () {
  invokeTransaction()
})
```

This might solve your memory leak problem. Also you might consider that the leaks comes from your method rather than the implementation of `setInterval` or the cron scheduler.

Comment: Funny, that's actually what I started with but still the same issue. I'll test more with the underlying MongoDB call.

Comment: You were right. It was the underlying code as I neglected to add `db.close()` to the MongoDB call.

Comment: According to node-schedule docs: "if you only want to do something like "run this function every 5 minutes", you'll find setInterval much easier to use, and far more appropriate"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the movement into global scope is causing the GC to keep these variables alive.

I would suggest you consider the exact opposite direction, using a container function and no global variables.

I have no idea how New Relic behaves, but is a dirty example of how your code might look like using this design:

```
const transactionName = 'email-scheduler';
function perform_transaction() {
  newrelic.createBackgroundTransaction(transactionName,
      function () {
        sendEmail(function (error) {
          log.info("Job completed; ending transaction.");
          newrelic.endTransaction();
        });
      });
}

function sendEmail(callback) {
  log.info('Scheduler woke up to send emails (set to send every ' + JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES + ' minutes)');
  mongo.findUsersSince(180, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      log.error("Welcome emails could not be sent: " + err);
      callback(err);
    }
    else if (result && result instanceof Array) {
      api.sendEmail(resutlt);
    } else {
      callback(null);
    }
  });
}

if (RUN_SCHEDULER) {
  setInterval(perform_transaction, JOB_INTERVAL_MINUTES * 1000 * 60);
}
```

I don't know if this helps, since I have no idea what the underlying API does... But in general, saving a variable in global space increases the risk of having that object eat up memory through references to obsolete data.

**EDIT**

The correct answer for this specific case (see comments both here and to @Aperçu's answer), discovered by @occasl was that the underlying API was missing a `db.close()` call.

Comment: I originally had the code in an exports block but point well taken. It still was leaking until added a `db.close()` to my MongoDB call.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval`is not a good software architecture implementation.
You can use [Node Cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)

```js
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 30 11 * * 1-5', function() {
  /*
   * Runs every weekday (Monday through Friday)
   * at 11:30:00 AM. It does not run on Saturday
   * or Sunday.
   */
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```

Comment: See comment below. Same issue.